# Proof of perpendicularity and points equality in a triangle with inequality on area

Tags: geometry, inequality, area

We have three points P, R, and S in a -dimensional plane with integer coordinates. Let  be the area of
triangle PRS,  be the length of the line segment PR and  be the length of the line segment PS.
We have the condition that $$( + )^2  <  + $$
I need to prove that  =  and that PR and PS are perpendicular.
I tried to approach the problem by making some drawings and seeing how to profit from the inequality condition and the integer constraint on the coordinates but with no result.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As can be seen in figure ,if PRS is right angled triangle then:

$S_{PRS}=Q=\frac{PR\cdot PS}2$

But: $PR=PS=PH\sqrt 2$

This gives maximum possible area of PRS because $PR=PS$ and we have:

$S_{PRS}=Q=\frac{(2PH)\cdot PH}2=PH^2\Rightarrow 8Q+1=8PH^2+1 $

And:

$(PR+PS)^2=(2PH\sqrt 2)^2=8PH^2$

Which suffice the inequality condition.

Comment: Actually, what I want is to prove that perpendicularity and the equality between C and D.